# can any data be fetched from the key generated to upload app on playstore?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, google-play-console, privacy

So, i am making a flutter app for my client. For uploading the app on playstore am generating the
upload key(.jks).I want to know whether on generating the key for the playstore can anyone take any important content from that key. Like can someone use that key to get data from my laptop or misuse it in any form. Is it safe to generate the key then upload app on playstore from your laptop and then give key to the client?

Comment: Yes, it is safe. Don't be so cynical!

Comment: So you mean I can generate the key and give it to my client without any worry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JKS file will contain the key and a certificate associated with the key:

- The key is only two or three very long numbers.
- The certificate associated with the key contains information such as Name, Company, Country, etc. (which you should have been prompted for when you created the certificate).

The key and certificate will only allow the client to sign future APKs/Bundles to upload to the Play Console, that's all. So yes, it's safe to give the JKS file to the client (assuming it was created just for that app).